# dotnetnuke 7 redirects to home when clicking edit mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, dotnetnuke

Have installed dotnetnuke 7 on a virtual server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

There were complications during install that required modifying various permissions but eventually completed the install. The site loads correctly and can log into superuser account. However, when I try to enter edit mode the page redirects back to the home page.

Any ideas?

Edit ---
Event View did show dbo.GetTopHtmlText was missing. Have done a complete reinstall and this are now present and Log Viewer show no exceptions but the page still redirects to Home when try to edit page.

Edit ---
Using Firefox Web Console have discovered the following:

```
Request URL: http://cmstrial/dotnetnuke/DesktopModules/internalservices/API/controlbar/ToggleUserMode

Request Method: POST

Status Code: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Not sure why I should be unauthorized as am logged in as SuperUser and have granted full control to the install directory for the AppPool as installation guide says.

Comment: Can you check the Event Viewer page to see if there are any errors being recorded?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for comment. See edit for Event Viewer log.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching managed to find this workaround. Adding the following to the modules tab in the web.config seems to have resolved the problem:

runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

for info view here
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/190/threadid/469106/scope/posts/threadpage/9.aspx